# Suavização de animação em JS

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou criando uma aplicação baseada em Vue.js. Essa aplicação deve conter alguns elementos que são animados de acordo com o mouse.

Criei as animações em javascript e percebe-se que os elementos ficam "tremendo" na tela, pode-se observar no seguinte vídeo: https://youtu.be/BN-hyMFO27M

Todos os elementos tem posição absoluta e são animados alterando sua posição na tela. Segue o código:

```
loadMouseMove: function () {
    this.resetarPosicoes();
    this.elementosMousemove = [];

    var elementos = document.getElementsByClassName('efeitomouse');
    for (var i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {

        var config = JSON.parse(elementos[i].getAttribute('mmconfig'));

        this.elementosMousemove.push({
            objeto: elementos[i],
            posicaoOriginal: {
                top: elementos[i].offsetTop,
                left: elementos[i].offsetLeft
            },
            fator: {
                x: config.fx,
                y: config.fy
            }
        });
    }
    this.mousemoveHabilitado = (elementos.length > 0);

    this.mousePosicaoAtual = {
        x: (this.tamanhoTela.width / 2),
        y: (this.tamanhoTela.height / 2)
    }

    this.mouseUltimaPosicao = {
        x: this.mousePosicaoAtual.x,
        y: this.mousePosicaoAtual.y
    }
},
resetarPosicoes: function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.elementosMousemove.length; i++) {
        this.elementosMousemove[i].objeto.style.left = '';
        this.elementosMousemove[i].objeto.style.top = '';
    }
},
mousemove: function (event) {

    app.mouseUltimaPosicao.x = event.x;
    app.mouseUltimaPosicao.y = event.y;

    if (app.mousemoveHabilitado) {
        cancelAnimationFrame(app.animationFrame);
        app.animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(app.animarMouseMove);
    }
},
animarMouseMove: function () {
    var deltaX = app.mouseUltimaPosicao.x - app.mousePosicaoAtual.x;
    var deltaY = app.mouseUltimaPosicao.y - app.mousePosicaoAtual.y;
    var deslocamentoMax = 20;

    if (deltaX > 0) {
        app.mousePosicaoAtual.x += (deltaX > deslocamentoMax) ? deslocamentoMax : deltaX;
    } else {
        app.mousePosicaoAtual.x += (deltaX < -deslocamentoMax) ? -deslocamentoMax : deltaX;
    }

    if (deltaY > 0) {
        app.mousePosicaoAtual.y += (deltaY > deslocamentoMax) ? deslocamentoMax : deltaY;
    } else {
        app.mousePosicaoAtual.y += (deltaY < -deslocamentoMax) ? -deslocamentoMax : deltaY;
    }

    app.moverElementosMousemove(app.mousePosicaoAtual.x, app.mousePosicaoAtual.y);

    if (Math.abs(deltaX) > 10 || Math.abs(deltaY) > 10) {
        app.animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(app.animarMouseMove);
    }
},
moverElementosMousemove(x, y) {
    var left = x - (app.tamanhoTela.width / 2);
    var top = y - (app.tamanhoTela.height / 2);

    for (var i = 0; i < app.elementosMousemove.length; i++) {
        var elemento = app.elementosMousemove[i];
        var px = elemento.posicaoOriginal.left + left * elemento.fator.x;
        var py = elemento.posicaoOriginal.top + top * elemento.fator.y;

        elemento.objeto.style.left = px + 'px';
        elemento.objeto.style.top = py + 'px';
    }
}
```

Há alguma forma de suavizar esse movimento para que esse efeito não ocorra mais?

## EDIT

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jpVjxG

Comment: Coloca o resto do codigo ai html e css

Comment: Parece um problema de arredondamento de valores quebrados.

Comment: Se você reduzir a velocidade do movimento do mouse, os elementos tremem nenos? Só pra saber se o problema está na perfomance da rotina ou cálculo.

Comment: O ideal é sempre utilizar a propriedade [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/transform) para animações no eixo X/Y por conta da [Aceleração via Hardware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20633548/694105).

Comment: como suar o transform via Javascript?

Comment: @Kazzkiq o hardware só vai ser ativado se vc usar propriedades que usam os 3 eixos de renderização, ou seja, transformZ, rotateZ, etc.

Comment: @Kazzkiq alterei pra usar o transform e resolveu o problema, poderia criar uma resposta pra essa pergunta?

Comment: @Pilati [feito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/316579/1754).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É considerado uma boa prática utilizar a propriedade [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/transform) do CSS3 sempre que você for fazer algum tipo de animação CSS.

Isto ocorre porque [certas propriedades](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20633548/694105) CSS possuem sua [renderização otimizada via hardware](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Performance/Performance_fundamentals), tornando possível o uso da GPU do dispositivo nas animações, o que melhora consideravelmente a performance, principalmente em dispositivos móveis.

Então, no seu caso, ao invés de usar propriedades como `top` e `left`, você poderia utilizar `translate3d(x, y, z)` para ativar esse tipo de otimização.

Exemplo:

```
// No lugar de left e top
elemento.objeto.style.left = px + 'px';
elemento.objeto.style.top = py + 'px';

// Usar transform
elemento.objeto.style.transform = `translate3d(${px}px, ${py}px, 0)`;
```

Answer (score -1):

Provavelmente se você adicionar um CSS ao objeto que recebe as propriedades `left` e `top` com uma determinada `transition` isso se resolva.

```
transition: .1s all ease;
```

Comment: Já tentei usar o `transition` e não funcionou. :/